# Awesomewm - Dividing rc.lua

Tags: linux, archlinux, awesome-wm

a few days ago I began to hit Awesomewm and a doubt came to me to customize. By standard AWM comes with a unique configuration file called RC.Lua, I would like to separate my Key Bindings from separate files.

Example:
Keybindings/keys1.Lua
Keybindings/keys2.Lua.

Besides that I would like to know the difference between clientkeys and globalkeys?

I was successful dividing the files, but one keys configuration file always excelled the other

Exemple:

keys1.lua

```
local beautiful = require("beautiful")
local hotkeys_popup = require("awful.hotkeys_popup")
local awful = require("awful")

------------------------------------------------
local my_table = awful.util.table or gears.table
------------------------------------------------


----------------------------------------------------
local config = require("config")
----------------------------------------------------

globalkeys = my_table.join(

-- modkey + enter = launch terminal
awful.key({modkey}, "Return", function()
    awful.spawn(terminal)
end, {
    description = "launch terminal",
    group = "awesome"
}))
```

keys2.lua

```
local beautiful = require("beautiful")
local hotkeys_popup = require("awful.hotkeys_popup")
local awful = require("awful")

------------------------------------------------
local my_table = awful.util.table or gears.table
------------------------------------------------


----------------------------------------------------
local config = require("config")
----------------------------------------------------

globalkeys = my_table.join(


-- modkey + "b" = launch browser
awful.key({modkey}, "b", function()
    awful.spawn(browser)
end, {
    description = "launch browser",
    group = "awesome"
}))
```

rc.lua

```
local keys1 = require("keys1")
local keys2 = require("keys2")
```

At this point the last place Keys surpass the first so ignoring the configuration made in the same

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In the git-master version of AwesomeWM, you get the [awful.keyboard.append_client_keybindings](https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/input_handling/awful.keyboard.html#append_client_keybindings) and  [awful.keyboard.append_global_keybindings](https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/input_handling/awful.keyboard.html#module.append_global_keybindings). You also get a `"request::default_keybindings"` signal on the `client` class.

Those APIs are designed for modular configs. Actually, you can cut and paste entire sections from the newer `rc.lua` into new files with minimal effort.